# Pivoting a table partially in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a table containing user reviews (numbers totally made-up):

```
| user_id | vote | votes_for_user | average_user_vote | ISBN_categ |
   213       4.5        12                  3.4             1 
   563       3.7        74                  2.3             2
   213       1.2        12                  3.6             3 
   213       3.2        74                  2.1             2
   213       1.9        12                  3.8             4 
   563       1.4        74                  2.6             1
   563       5.0        74                  2.9             4
```

I want to place the `vote` of every user into a corresponding column, headed by the `ISBN_categ` value, with 0 where no votes where given.

```
| user_id | votes_for_user | average_user_vote | ISBN_cat_1 | ISBN_cat_2 | ISBN_cat_3 | ISBN_cat_4 |
   213           12               3.4                4.5          3.2           1.2        1.9
   563           74               2.3                1.4          3.7           0.0        5.0
```

Notice how, due to the fact that user 563 did not vote for book number 3 (ISBN_cat_3 in the second table or 3 in ISBN_categ in the first table), the assigned value is 0.0

I understand this is some kind of pivoting of the table, however I can't find anything similar in the Pandas documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) first and then remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) if necessary and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) together:

```
df1 = df.pivot('user_id','ISBN_categ','vote').fillna(0).add_prefix('ISBN_cat_')

df = df.drop_duplicates('user_id').join(df1, on='user_id').drop('vote', axis=1)
print (df)
   user_id  votes_for_user  average_user_vote  ISBN_categ  ISBN_cat_1  \
0      213              12                3.4           1         4.5   
1      563              74                2.3           2         1.4   

   ISBN_cat_2  ISBN_cat_3  ISBN_cat_4  
0         3.2         1.2         1.9  
1         3.7         0.0         5.0
```